# I am receiving org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtProperty on build

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently using Kotlin 1.4.31 when I try and compile the code that was converted from java it does not build. Instead it gives me a error which I do not understand.

> Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtProperty

```
class SummaryFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    var imgBack: ImageView? = null
    var cardLayout: LinearLayout? = null
    var noOfRideTxt: CountAnimationTextView? = null
    var scheduleTxt: CountAnimationTextView? = null
    var revenueTxt: CountAnimationTextView? = null
    var cancelTxt: CountAnimationTextView? = null
    var ridesCard: CardView? = null
    var cancelCard: CardView? = null
    var scheduleCard: CardView? = null
    var revenueCard: CardView? = null
    var currencyTxt: TextView? = null
    var rides = 0
    var revenue = 0
    var schedule = 0
    var cancel = 0
    var doubleRevenue: Double? = null
    var TAG = "SummaryFragment"

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false)

        findViewsById(view)
        setClickListeners()
        providerSummary
        return view
    }

    private fun setClickListeners() {
        imgBack!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        revenueCard!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        ridesCard!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        revenueCard!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        scheduleCard!!.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun findViewsById(view: View) {
        imgBack = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.backArrow) as ImageView
        cardLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.card_layout) as LinearLayout
        noOfRideTxt = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.no_of_rides_txt) as CountAnimationTextView
        scheduleTxt = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.schedule_txt) as CountAnimationTextView
        cancelTxt = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.cancel_txt) as CountAnimationTextView
        revenueTxt = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.revenue_txt) as CountAnimationTextView
        currencyTxt = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.currency_txt) as TextView
        revenueCard = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.revenue_card) as CardView
        scheduleCard = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.schedule_card) as CardView
        ridesCard = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.rides_card) as CardView
        cancelCard = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.cancel_card) as CardView
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        val manager = fragmentManager
        val transaction = manager!!.beginTransaction()
        var fragment = Fragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("toolbar", "true")
        when (v.id) {
            R.id.backArrow -> //                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                activity!!.onBackPressed()
            R.id.rides_card -> {
                fragment = PastTrips()
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment, TAG)
                transaction.addToBackStack(TAG)
                transaction.commit()
            }
            R.id.schedule_card -> {
                fragment = OnGoingTrips()
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment, TAG)
                transaction.addToBackStack(TAG)
                transaction.commit()
            }
            R.id.revenue_card -> {
                fragment = EarningsFragment()
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment, TAG)
                transaction.addToBackStack(TAG)
                transaction.commit()
            }
            R.id.cancel_card -> {
                fragment = PastTrips()
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment, TAG)
                transaction.addToBackStack(TAG)
                transaction.commit()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setDetails() {
        val txtAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.txt_size)
        if (schedule > 0) {
            scheduleTxt!!.setAnimationDuration(500)
                    .countAnimation(0, schedule)
        } else {
            scheduleTxt!!.text = "0"
        }
        if (revenue > 0) {
            revenueTxt!!.setAnimationDuration(500)
                    .countAnimation(0, revenue)
        } else {
            revenueTxt!!.text = "0"
        }
        if (rides > 0) {
            noOfRideTxt!!.setAnimationDuration(500)
                    .countAnimation(0, rides)
        } else {
            noOfRideTxt!!.text = "0"
        }
        if (cancel > 0) {
            cancelTxt!!.setAnimationDuration(500)
                    .countAnimation(0, cancel)
        } else {
            cancelTxt!!.text = "0"
        }
        scheduleTxt!!.startAnimation(txtAnim)
        revenueTxt!!.startAnimation(txtAnim)
        noOfRideTxt!!.startAnimation(txtAnim)
        cancelTxt!!.startAnimation(txtAnim)
        currencyTxt!!.text = getKey(context!!, "currency")
    }

   // revenue = Integer.parseInt(response.optString("revenue"))
    val providerSummary: Unit
        get() {
            run {
                val customDialog = CustomDialog(requireActivity())
                customDialog.setCancelable(false)
                customDialog.show()
                val `object` = JSONObject()
                val jsonObjectRequest: JsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, URLHelper.SUMMARY, `object`, Response.Listener { response ->
                    try {
                        customDialog.dismiss()
                        val slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), R.anim.slide_up)
                        cardLayout?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        cardLayout?.startAnimation(slideUp)
                        rides = response.optString("rides").toInt()
                        schedule = response.optString("scheduled_rides").toInt()
                        cancel = response.optString("cancel_rides").toInt()
                        doubleRevenue = response.optString("revenue").toDouble()
                        revenue = doubleRevenue!!.toInt()
                        //revenue = Integer.parseInt(response.optString("revenue"));
                        slideUp.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
                            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}
                            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
                                setDetails()
                            }

                            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
                        })
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    customDialog.dismiss()
                    var json: String? = null
                    var Message: String
                    val response = error.networkResponse
                    if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                        try {
                            val errorObj = JSONObject(String(response.data))
                            if (response.statusCode == 400 || response.statusCode == 405 || response.statusCode == 500) {
                                try {
                                    displayMessage(errorObj.optString("message"))
                                } catch (e: Exception) {
                                    displayMessage(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong))
                                    e.printStackTrace()
                                }
                            } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
                                GoToBeginActivity()
                            } else if (response.statusCode == 422) {
                                json = trimMessage(String(response.data))
                                if (json !== "" && json != null) {
                                    displayMessage(json)
                                } else {
                                    displayMessage(getString(R.string.please_try_again))
                                }
                            } else if (response.statusCode == 503) {
                                displayMessage(getString(R.string.server_down))
                            } else {
                                displayMessage(getString(R.string.please_try_again))
                            }
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            displayMessage(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong))
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (error is NoConnectionError) {
                            displayMessage(getString(R.string.oops_connect_your_internet))
                        } else if (error is NetworkError) {
                            displayMessage(getString(R.string.oops_connect_your_internet))
                        } else if (error is TimeoutError) {
                            providerSummary
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String>? {
                        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                        headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
                        headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + getKey(context!!, "access_token")
                        Log.e("", "Access_Token" + getKey(context!!, "access_token"))
                        return headers
                    }
                }
                d.instance?.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
            }
        }

    fun displayMessage(toastString: String?) {
        Snackbar.make(view!!, toastString!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }

    fun GoToBeginActivity() {
        putKey(context!!, "loggedIn", getString(R.string.False))
        val mainIntent = Intent(context, WelcomeScreenActivity::class.java)
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(mainIntent)
        activity!!.finish()
    }
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtProperty
File being compiled: (172,25) in /Users/s/Downloads/app/src/main/java/com/d/s/Fragment/SummaryFragment.kt
The root cause java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.CodegenContext.getOuterExpression(CodegenContext.java:222)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:340)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1342)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1289)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitBlockExpression(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitBlockExpression(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBlockExpression.accept(KtBlockExpression.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:316)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:422)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.lambda$generateTryExpression$34(ExpressionCodegen.java:5033)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValueWithLeaveTask.putSelector(StackValue.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:442)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1846)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClosureGenerationStrategy.doGenerateBody(ClosureGenerationStrategy.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:649)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:484)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:260)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClosureCodegen.generateClosureBody(ClosureCodegen.java:206)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClosureCodegen.generateBody(ClosureCodegen.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genClosure(ExpressionCodegen.java:1104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genClosure(ExpressionCodegen.java:1069)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genSamInterfaceValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:2467)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:2442)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:316)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:298)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitDotQualifiedExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:3531)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitDotQualifiedExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtDotQualifiedExpression.accept(KtDotQualifiedExpression.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:316)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:298)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:414)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultCallGenerator.genValueAndPut(CallGenerator.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallBasedArgumentGenerator.generateExpression(CallBasedArgumentGenerator.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ArgumentGenerator.generate(ArgumentGenerator.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.lambda$visitObjectLiteralExpression$7(ExpressionCodegen.java:1165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.initializeLocalVariable(ExpressionCodegen.java:4658)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitProperty(ExpressionCodegen.java:4526)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitProperty(ExpressionCodegen.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtProperty.accept(KtProperty.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitKtElement(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitKtElement(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitExpression(KtVisitor.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitDeclaration(KtVisitor.java:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitNamedDeclaration(KtVisitor.java:398)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitProperty(KtVisitor.java:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtProperty.accept(KtProperty.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:316)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1342)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1289)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1026)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBlockExpression.accept(KtBlockExpression.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:316)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:298)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:414)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:422)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1846)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClosureGenerationStrategy.doGenerateBody(ClosureGenerationStrategy.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:649)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiSourceCompilerForInline.generateMethodBody(SourceCompilerForInline.kt:206)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiSourceCompilerForInline.generateLambdaBody(SourceCompilerForInline.kt:153)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.ExpressionLambda.generateLambdaBody(LambdaInfo.kt:231)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.generateClosuresBodies(InlineCodegen.kt:359)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.inlineCall(InlineCodegen.kt:220)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:143)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiInlineCodegen.genCallInner(PsiInlineCodegen.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultImpls.genCall(CallGenerator.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiInlineCodegen.genCall(PsiInlineCodegen.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2772)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2714)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValueWithLeaveTask.putSelector(StackValue.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:442)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1846)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:649)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:484)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:260)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PropertyCodegen.generateAccessor(PropertyCodegen.java:545)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PropertyCodegen.generateGetter(PropertyCodegen.java:506)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PropertyCodegen.gen(PropertyCodegen.java:142)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PropertyCodegen.gen(PropertyCodegen.java:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genSimpleMember(MemberCodegen.java:208)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassBodyCodegen.java:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:595)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Don't know how to generate outer expression: Class: class SummaryFragment
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.CodegenContext.getOuterExpression(CodegenContext.java:222)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.CodegenContext.lookupInContext(CodegenContext.java:563)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.MethodContext.lookupInContext(MethodContext.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.CodegenContext.lookupInContext(CodegenContext.java:573)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.MethodContext.lookupInContext(MethodContext.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.CodegenContext.lookupInContext(CodegenContext.java:573)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.MethodContext.lookupInContext(MethodContext.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.context.MethodContext.generateReceiver(MethodContext.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateExtensionReceiver(ExpressionCodegen.java:3135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateReceiverValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:3027)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.genReceiver(StackValue.java:862)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.receiver(StackValue.java:838)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putReceiverAndInlineMarkerIfNeeded(ExpressionCodegen.java:2824)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2734)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2714)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultCallGenerator.genValueAndPut(CallGenerator.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallBasedArgumentGenerator.generateExpression(CallBasedArgumentGenerator.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ArgumentGenerator.generate(ArgumentGenerator.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2743)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2714)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.initializeLocalVariable(ExpressionCodegen.java:4658)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitProperty(ExpressionCodegen.java:4526)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitProperty(ExpressionCodegen.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtProperty.accept(KtProperty.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitKtElement(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitKtElement(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitExpression(KtVisitor.java:182)
    ... 151 more
```

Comment: Can you post the java file from which this kt file is generated ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA here is a link to the GitHub for that file: [link](https://github.com/aowusuda/Codecheck/blob/main/SummaryFragment.kt) <-- Kt [link](https://github.com/aowusuda/Codecheck/blob/main/SummaryFragment.java)<-Java